# Is it better to use divs or tables to contain columns of links?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-tables

I have a page with 3 columns of links at the bottom. Each column is put into a div and all three divs are wrapped into a big div that is centered on the page. Is this something that is better suited to a table or is a table the wrong element for the job?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also use [`<ul>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) & [`<li>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_li.asp) for this.

```
#horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    float: left;
}

#horizontal ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 12em;
    float: left;
}
```

This will create horizontal columns using li elements, and then you can stuff the HTML to create individual links in each li.

Comment: +1 for semantics.  What the OP is describing is a *list* of links.  It ought to be a *list* element.  :-)

Comment: If each list has its own title, you could use `<dl>` instead, with `<dt>` and the title and `<dd>` for each of the links.

Answer (score 2):

The Rule of Thumb is:

Use Divs for layout, tables for tabular data.

On a side note, check out etymology of the term Rule of Thumb, quite humorous.

Comment: I consistently run into the following problem: I follow the rule of thumb, so I use DIVs.  Then I get some interfering styles at some point, which forces me to try a TABLE... and it just works.

Comment: Whenever it comes to style, there should be some way/hack to accomplish. AND if it really can't works, I would try JS to help in the styling. 

No matter what, I will not trade off the PROPER formatting for pure display decision.

Comment: "Rule of Thumb" does NOT come from wife-beating, if that's what you meant :p

Answer (score 0):

the question you want to ask yourself is, are your links a part of any tabular data?

if yes, tables are your choice. If no, then you should use divs.

Its important to use the semantically correect element to create a page, although other elements may result in the same effect, possibly with less effort.

As for your links, it seems they are not part of a table. I'd suggest the use of divs and proper css.

jrh

Answer (score 0):

I don't think tables are a good choice for this. Simply having three columns doesn't constitute tabular data in my book. With some clean markup and a good stylesheet, you can have a much more flexible way to accomplish this. If you use left floated divs, simply give them a percent width so that they fill up the parent container (100 / number of elements)%. That way, if you want to add another column its a simple markup change a single stylesheet change. This way you wont have to deal with browser table wonkyness and have a great deal more flexibility in its design - on top of that you can change the layout completely without leaving your stylesheet.

Comment: I'd suggest that you amend the percentage calculation to something akin to (floor(100/number-of-elements))% just to allow for the browser's percentage width-to-pixels issues. I can't remember if this is particularly worse in one browser or another, but it can occasionally cause problems if the widths equal exactly 100%, especially if borders are also added.

Answer (score 0):

The main principle behind HTML is to "markup" the **MEANING** of your data.

I'll use the above principle as a guide:

1. If you have 3 columns just because it looks nice - then there is no meaning to your columns, and you should try to use DIVs (which are meaningless "container" elements).
2. If you have 3 columns because there are 3 categories of links, then a TABLE is fine.  Imagine if you gave headers to each list of links - this makes a TABLE with a THEAD **necessary**.
3. And in fact, each column is an "unordered list" - which translates into a UL element with LI elements.
4. And since you have a list of links, you will use, of course, A elements.

So from first-principles, you should have this structure:

```
<DIV> or <TABLE> (with <TR>/<TD>)
 -> <UL>
 ----> <LI>
 -------- <A>
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to other answers, a table could be a semantic solution. If the three sections are distinct from each other and have a title, you can use `<th>` for the titles and `<td>` for each of the links. I think that's perfectly semantic.