# How can I line block elements up in a row?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several block a elements that I want to be side-by-side to create a menu. The width of each is set to auto to accommodate the text inside. Each a element is displayed as a table cell and can work with either absolute or relative positioning.

Thanks for any help.
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

display:inline-block

Comment: Note that `inline-block` is not supported in certain browsers that are popular on the market today.

Answer (score 2):

If you float block elements, they'll be placed in a horizontal row (with dynamic widths unless you specify a fixed one.)

```
ul#navigation li {
    float: left;
}
```

Have a look at the HTML for the navigation on this page, for example (Questions, Tags, Users, ...)

Answer (score 0):

This is [an almost similar scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107669/is-it-better-to-use-divs-or-tables-to-contain-columns-of-links/1107692#1107692) which you can consider using for creating a menu.

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone with `display:inline-block` for generic side-by-side display but you're trying to do a horizontal nav. I wouldn't use the table cell display as it's quirky and you'll end up having to clean up other bugs.

**Html:**

```css
#navigation{
  width:550px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#navigation li{
  float:left;
}

#navigation li a,#navigation li a:hover{
  display:block;
  padding:4px 21px 4px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navigation">
  <li ><a href="/some-link.html">Some link</a></li>
  <li ><a href="/some-link2.html">Some link 2</a></li>
  <li ><a href="/some-link3.html">Some link three</a></li>
</ul>
```